# Dragging class created objects in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

apology for bad english

So I was doing a program and want the label created in class to move by dragging it with mouse
but whatever I try to do it doesnt work and doesnt want to move
this is my code:

```py
class Note:
    def __init__(self,master):
        myFrame = Frame(master)
        myFrame.place(x=50,y=50)
        
        self.myLabel = Label(myFrame, text="Text",font=("Arial",20))  
        self.myLabel.pack()
        self.myFrame = myFrame

        self.myFrame.bind("<Button-1>",self.drag_start)
        self.myFrame.bind("<B1-Motion>",self.drag_motion)
        

    def drag_start(self,event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.startX = event.x
        widget.startY = event.y

    def drag_motion(self,event):
        widget = event.widget
        x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
        y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
        widget.place(x=x,y=y)

e = Note(root)
```

what can I do to make it start moving when dragging by mouse?

Comment: Try using `self.myLabel.bind` instead of `self.myFrame.bind`.

Comment: i did and i forgot to add i get error     label.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
NameError: name 'drag_start' is not defined

Comment: You missed the `self.` before the `drag_start`.

Comment: but there is self. before drag_start i dont know how is it not defined when it is

Comment: ok it works with label alone but I want to move the frame because i want to add some more objects into it, but frame doesnt move

Comment: The problem is that if you bind the label, the frame isn't going to move. If you bind the frame, the label isn't going to be drag-able. Look at how `.bind_all` works. But it will be a headache to use - personal experience.

Comment: ok .bind_all works thank you

Comment: I think the implementation would be a bit cleaner if `Note` inherited from `Frame`. Is there a specific reason why you did not do it that way?

Comment: Be careful about using `bind_all` as it literally binds to all elements and not just this frame and label. It's not clear if whether or not that's what you actually want.